# Is there a mathematical operator to truncate negative values to zero?

Tags: notation

Is there a mathematical symbol that truncates a value *x* to 0 if it is negative, and leaves it untouched otherwise? Something which is logically equivalent to $\max(x, 0)$?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have seen the notation $z^+$ to denote $\max\{z,0\}$ in many papers and books. Analogously, $z^-$ to denote $-\min\{z,0\}$. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_and_negative_parts) uses that notation too.

---

**EDIT (thanks to @rzippo)** : Note that $z^-$ denotes the so-called *negative part*, which is non-negative. If we want a function that simply *truncates positive values to zero*, then we would need the function $f(z)=\min\{z,0\}$ (without the minus sign), for which I do not know any particular notation.

Comment: This is freaking awesome and it gives me goosebumps. I am solving a programming issue. And I had the same question. This shows that know your math can help you where you expect it the least. Instead of writing 3 lines of code, I will just call the `max()` function which takes an unlimited number of arguments and 0 will be one of them. I love Math. Thanks for this answer.

Comment: @asiby Thanks! I think that was the most grateful comment anyone wrote to me in SE.

Comment: Thanks to you. You are very welcome. I was speaking from the heart. Keep up contributing. ;)

Comment: One thing I was finding confusing is the minus sign in $z^- = -\min\{z,0\}$. What you are describing is the _negative part_ function, which is meant to be non-negative. It does not simply _truncate positive values_, as one would expect given the context of this answer.

Comment: @rzippo I think we are both right. If we talk about _truncating positive values_, the minus sign should not appear. But it is also true, that when talking about the operator $z^+$ (the real aim of the question), it is also worth talking about its _pair_ $z^-$, isn't it? Anyway, thanks for the clarification. I will add it to the answer.

Answer (score 16):

How about adding the absolute value of the number to the number, and then dividing by 2.  If the number is negative, the total will be zero, which divided by 2 is still zero.  If the number is positive or zero, the result will be the number you began with.

Comment: This is a good answer, but not to quite the right question - this one asks for a symbol. Upvoted as I came here looking for a method rather than a symbol!

Comment: As a matter of fact, this would be a particular case of using $\max(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}(x+y+|x-y|)$ for $y=0$, which relates to my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac12(x+\sqrt{x^2})$ will zero all negative values of $f(x)$.

$\frac12(x-\sqrt{x^2})$ will zero all positive values of $f(x)$.