# Is there a mathematical notation to denote truncation to a proportion?

Tags: notation

Is there an established mathematical notation/symbol for truncating a variable to values between zero and one, i.e. to a proportion? This would be equivalent to $\min(\max(x,\,0),\,1)$?

Via [Is there a mathematical operator to truncate negative values to zero?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1351080/is-there-a-mathematical-operator-to-truncate-negative-values-to-zero) I've found that one may use $x^+ = \max(x,\,0)$ ...

Comment: Not that I remember. That doesn't seem like a thing you would often do...

Comment: That function often named as $clamp(x, 0, 1)$.

Comment: Suggestion: $\operatorname{clamp_0^1} (x)$ might be a bit more succinct then. Or maybe something like $[x|_0^1$ might be a good notation.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and suggestions. I've settled for this notation: $\left[x\right]_0^1$.